# SQS does not trigger Lambda within 5 minutes in sequential

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm new to AWS and working on SQS to trigger a lambda function.
The order of the function is,
Lambda A and pass queue to SQS, then SQS trigger Lambda B.

When I run Lambda A, I see Lambda B is triggered as I expected. However, when I run Lambda A within 5 minutes after the last run of Lambda A, Lambda B is not triggered. I'm wondering if there is a default time set of "5 minutes" to use SQS triggering Lambda function. If so, how can I change to "0 minute"?

Does anybody have the similar issue before? Thanks,

```
// Lambda A
// sends multiple messages to an Amazon SQS queue
module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    // sendQueue function is imported in the head of the file
    await sendQueue({ queueMessage }, QUEUE_URL)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: 'Lambda A is done',
        input: event,
      },
      null,
      2
    ),
  }
}

// Lambda B
// After SQS receives queues from Lambda A, SQS triggers to invoke Lambda B
module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  // here calling Athena query with "await"
  return `Successfully processed a message.`;
}
```

In Lambda B, it gets a message content everytime the function receives a message from SQS like below.

```
[
  {
    messageId: 'b4146e42-a542-4e0e-bff9-ba7f96xxxxxx',
    receiptHandle: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    body: '{"queueMessage": "queueMessage sample text"}',
    attributes: {
      ApproximateReceiveCount: '1',
      SentTimestamp: '1643094105466',
      SequenceNumber: '18867376164708847616',
      MessageGroupId: '123',
      SenderId: 'xxxxxxxx:lambda-function-name',
      MessageDeduplicationId: 'xxxxxx',
      ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp: '1643094105466'
    },
    messageAttributes: { ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: [Object] },
    md5OfMessageAttributes: 'aaaaaaaa',
    md5OfBody: 'bbbbbbb',
    eventSource: 'aws:sqs',
    eventSourceARN: 'arn:aws:xxx.fifo',
    awsRegion: 'ap-northeast-1'
  }
]
```

Comment: We need your help by providing us more information bro, Can you share us the code that publishes the message in the queue? It will be cool to see the code used to define/provision the SQS queue too

Comment: Are you saying that Lambda A sends a message to an Amazon SQS queue, and that is used as a trigger to invoke Lambda B? If so, can you see the message waiting in the SQS queue? Also, please Edit your question to show how your Lambda B function is retrieving messages -- a common error is that the function only looks at the _first_ message that might be passed into the function, rather than looping through _ALL_ event records that have been passed in.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comment. I added the code.

Comment: Your code for Lambda B is showing the count of records that were sent to Lambda B. Are you saying the count is too small? Also, you didn't answer about whether you can see messages waiting in the SQS queue.

Comment: Updated the question. Sorry, I modified the code in Lambda B. since it did not make sense (The count is always 1 since every time SQS receives a queue message, it invoke Lambda B in my understanding). The problem is when I run Lambda A twice, I need to wait for 5 minutes to run the second one so that Lambda B is invoked somehow, otherwise, like run the second time Lambda A in 3 minutes, I don't see a log of Lambda B in Cloud Watch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After going over [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagededuplicationid-property.html), I found the line below

> If a message with a particular message deduplication ID is sent
> successfully, any messages sent with the same message deduplication ID
> are accepted successfully but aren't delivered during the 5-minute
> deduplication interval.

Basically, using FIFO queue of SQS, the messages sent during 5 minutes won't be delivered to avoid sending duplicate messages.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein! I should have mentioned that SQS queue I was using was FIFO. Thanks again for your helpful advice though :)

Answer (score 1):

Just ensure that you have not set the below setting in SQS. This setting could delay your Lambda function to running after x time.

[image: SQS Config]

Comment: Thanks! Mine is set as "0" Seconds in Delivery delay but happening the issue.