# SQS queue sometimes freezes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

SQS sometimes stops receiving messages or allowing message consumption, then resumes after ~5 mins. Do you know if there is a setting that can produce this behavior? I was playing around with the settings but could not change this behavior.

Notice: When I send a message, I get the ID and the OK as it was received, but the message is not in the queue.

Comment: Amazon SQS is a highly available, highly distributed system that handles millions of messages a second. It does not 'freeze'. Please Edit your question to provide more information about what you are experiencing and what you mean by "stops receiving messages or allowing message consumption". Also, please tell us how you are checking for messages in the queue and whether you are using a Standard or a FIFO queue. Code examples help too!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an ID and message is not in the queue,I believe you are using FIFO and it ignores dupliate messages within a default time frame (5 min. ?).  Whatever is feeding the queue need to use a good deduplication id in case if you want to process duplicate messages.
[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70842900/sqs-does-not-trigger-lambda-within-5-minutes-in-sequential)